# Вычислить сумму чисел

Tags: c++, ряды

Считать целые числа и вычислить:

[image]

Comment: @Just_kiss_me, используйте, пожалуйста, русский язык

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если элементарно закодить формулу, то:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 50;
    double s = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        s += 1.0/(i * i * i);
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

возникает только вопрос о чём речь в словах:

> Read any int as input

Comment: вот я сам не понял шапку задания, но ваш код принят системой) спасибо большое, я в этом деле новичок и пытаюсь освоится)